# NW.js: Failed to parse SessionDescription. Failed to parse audio codecs correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, node-webkit, peerjs

We are building a video chat with peerjs (Webrtc). We have a nodewebkit version and a chrome version.
But for some reason, if chrome start a mediastream to nodewebkit, We get the follow errors in nw.

```
PeerJS:  Creating RTCPeerConnection.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for ICE candidates.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for `negotiationneeded`
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for data channel
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Listening for remote stream
peerJS:  Setting remote description RTCSessionDescription {sdp: "v=0↵o=- 2956768960815374026 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1↵s…5525 label:87a9904d-945d-4393-ad98-68be98482104↵", type: "offer"}
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  ERROR Error: Failed to parse SessionDescription.  Failed to parse audio codecs correctly.
callingManager.js:293 webrtc:Failed to parse SessionDescription.  Failed to parse audio codecs correctly.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  Failed to setRemoteDescription,  Failed to parse SessionDescription.  Failed to parse audio codecs correctly.
8peer.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The ICE candidate could not be added.
```

So the error is:

```
Error: Failed to parse SessionDescription.  Failed to parse audio codecs correctly.
```

nodewebkit to Chrome works well.

Nw Version: v0.12.3
Chrome version: 46

Is this a media condec problem? Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome 46 changed the protocol in the SDP m-line from "RTP/SAVPF" to "UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF". It seems node-webkit is on a really old webrtc version (>1 year) that can't deal with this.

This has been announced for quite a while. See https://twitter.com/juberti/status/656535175635963904 et al.

Munge your SDP and replace "UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF" with "RTP/SAVPF".

Comment: Sorry, I am am not very expienced. How can I do that? I cant find that on google. Thanks!

Comment: After playing with peerjs, I understood what you meant. Now it is working. Thank you very much! Do you think I need to explain what I changed in peerjs?

Comment: @Beatnory, can you please mention what change you made ?

Comment: In peer.js I added "offer.sdp = offer.sdp.replace("UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF", "RTP/SAVPF");" on line 610 and line 617